# How can I run a csh script from a tcl script?

Tags: unix, tcl, csh

I am trying to run a csh script from a tcl script.

The tcl script below calls a csh script

```
#!/usr/bin/tclsh


set scripts_path /scratch/TCL_scripts/scripts_adders

set synthesis /scratch/TCL_scripts/synthesis.csh


set files [glob -directory $scripts_path *]
split $files
set files [lsort $files]
set i 1

foreach script $files {

     puts "hello"
     # puts [pwd]
     exec /bin/csh -c $synthesis
     puts $i

}
```

And the (begining of the) csh file is below:

```
#!/bin/csh -f


echo abcdefgh
```

When I only execute the csh file from my unix terminal, it works fine.
When I call my Tcl script, it runs and indeed writes "hello" and prints i, but the csh file is not executed because "abcdefgh" never appears in the terminal. I have also tried other commands, and I always have the same problem: the csh script is never executed when I run it from a Tcl script, even though it runs fine when I run it directly from the terminal.

(Both my Tcl script ans csh script are executable)

What must I do in order to run my csh script from my Tcl script ?

Thank you very much

Comment: As a side note, the call to [split $files] is extraneous. First, split returns the split list and you're not saving the result. Second, because glob already returns the filenames as a list and, if you treat it as a string and split on it, its just going to wind up breaking on filenames with spaces in them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The csh script is indeed run for you, but by default its standard output becomes the *result* of the Tcl `exec` command (and if it produced anything on standard error, that would become an *error* result of the `exec`). To make the output and error appear on the terminal, you have to modify the `exec` like this:

```
exec /bin/csh -c $synthesis >@stdout 2>@stderr
```

The `>@` says “redirect standard output to the following channel” (`stdout` in this case), and the `2>@` does the same for standard error.

Comment: You could've also done `puts [exec ...]` but I think what I proposed is more like what you wanted.

Comment: @Scooter: As the message in the error thrown by `exec`. This *does* potentially lose information.