# TCL exec output delayed

Tags: tcl, exec

I have a c-shell script that hypothetically does a ton of things and gives little messages along the way.

Example (test.csh):

```
#!/bin/csh
echo "hello world."
sleep 10
echo "hello again."
sleep 10
```

I am calling the script from tclsh.

```
exec /bin/csh test.csh
```

All the output is held back until end of the script. That is not desired. Desired outcome is to get output from the script as it happens. How would I modify the TCL call to achieve the desired outcome?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked out previous posts? See, e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13341427/how-can-i-run-a-csh-script-from-a-tcl-script/13342061#13342061

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I run a csh script from a tcl script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13341427/how-can-i-run-a-csh-script-from-a-tcl-script)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach could be as follows:

```
exec >@stdout 2>@stderr /bin/csh test.csh
```

Check out the corresponding sections of the `exec` manpage, e.g.: [>@](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/exec.htm#M19)

It turns out that your question has been raised before: [How can I run a csh script from a tcl script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13341427/how-can-i-run-a-csh-script-from-a-tcl-script/13342061#13342061)